# Difference between Dbgeng.dll distrubuted with windows 7 and debugging tools for windows package

Tags: windbg

What's missing in dbgeng.dll in windows 7 Vs the dbgeng.dll distributed with debugging tools for windows ?

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party on this one but I've run into one very significant difference recently:

The dbgeng.dll built into windows installations will not support remote debugging where as the one installed with debugging tools does!

There appear to be other differences also that I didn't dig deeper into - all I knew was a working program using the built in dll started crashing when using the debugging tools one... which was a pain considering I would have liked to use the remote debugging facility out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This post shows the difference between Windows 7 and Windows 8 preview, I believe Windows 8 version is similar or possibly same as latest one that ships that is in debugging tools because when I do use dependencyWalker I notice that the one in Debugging Tools also has this new exported method `DebugCreateEx` which is also in the latest [version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrew_richards/archive/2011/09/24/debugger-engine-dbgeng-updates-in-windows-8-developer-preview.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Microsoft%2FMSDN-Blogs+%28MSDN+Blogs%29)

Windows 7 System 32 version:

[image]

Dependency walker:
[image]

Debugging tools version:

[image]

Dependency walker:

[image]

Hope this helps in some way to explain the differences, especially the post at the top.

Comment: I have already performed such exercises in the past. The problem there is no definite answer, I loaded both the dlls in windbg and figured some of the functions are missing.

Comment: @Addy yeah it is a systemic problem with WinDbg in that the documentation is so poor, the only way would be to dump all the symbols for the 2 different dlls and compare them but it doesn't tell you what the new functions do.